# Change language of app

Tags: android, locale

I'm trying to change the language of my app.

I implement this code :

```
public static void setLocale(Resources res, String lang) {
    Configuration conf =  new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

    switch (lang) {
        case "French" :
            conf.locale = new Locale("fr");
            break;
        case "Dutch" :
            conf.locale = new Locale("nl");
            break;
        case "English" :
            conf.locale = new Locale("en");
            break;
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And after that I refresh my activity using this code :

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);
getActivity().finish();
startActivity(refresh);
```

This code works, but when I close the app (remove from background) and reopen it, the language return to the default language of my device.

Is there any way to keep the selected language when I reopen my app ?

Comment: you can store value in `SharedPreferences` and later on can fetch it and decide which language was selected before.

Comment: Why don't you let the user decide the language based on his device language?

Comment: Because I have to implement this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store in default shared Preference:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().edit().putString("Locale", localVal).commit();
```

and than every time the app start retrive it by:

```
locale = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().getString("Locale", "defaultValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my application, its working fine,Give a try hope it will help you

```
 public static void changeLanguageSettings(Context context,String language){        
    try{
        Locale mLocale = new Locale(language);
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();
        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(configuration);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            newConfig.setLocale(mLocale);
        }else{
            newConfig.locale = mLocale;
        }
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, dm);          
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, I didn't test it but I keep it in mind :)